# css Height on container

Tags: css, sass

I will need some help for the template of my website I'm lost with CSS heights and how they are made.

To understand my issue better I've created an codepen where its possible to visualise my issue in a simple way [link](https://codepen.io/lcsaloon/pen/zYMErNJ)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  width: 100wh;
  over-flow: hidden;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.boxtop {
  with: auto;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  grid-column: span 4 / span 4;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="boxtop"></div>
    <div class="gridcontainer">
      <div class="box">d</div>
      <div class="box">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this link you will see that the yellow part goes way over and I want it to stop at the end of the blue part.

Each box should have the height of `container2` - `boxtop`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `with` and `over-flow` are invalid CSS properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, some typos: `wh` is an invalid unit, `with` is not `width`, `over-flow` should be `overflow`

- use CSS `flex`
- you don't necessarily need the `20px height` if you'll have content in the `.boxtop`. Let flex calculate the necessary spaces for you
- use the `dvh` unit for dynamic viewport height

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

.container2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1.25rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
}

.boxtop {
  background-color: pink;
}

.gridcontainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.box {
  grid-column: span 4 / span 4;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="boxtop">top</div>
    <div class="gridcontainer">
      <div class="box">box 1</div>
      <div class="box">box 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this update `box` height to this `height: calc(100% - 20px);`. Also, `with` and `over-flow` are invalid CSS properties. `wh` is invalid CSS unit. Update it to `overflow: hidden;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.boxtop {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  grid-column: span 4 / span 4;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="boxtop"></div>
    <div class="gridcontainer">
      <div class="box">d</div>
      <div class="box">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `over-flow:` ? you mean `overflow`?

Comment: `with: auto;` ? What is `with`?

Comment: Remove the height: 100%; from .box as it was causing the yellow box to overflow beyond the grid container and fix it to this height: calc(100% - 20px).

Comment: Yes, with and over-flow are invalid css properties. I have updated the code with correct CSS properties. @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: What is `wh` in `width: 100wh;`?

Comment: It should be width: 100vw; not wh @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

You will need to choose the units properly so that they are compatible with each other. For example, in your original code, you have set the container height in **vh** units, padding in **rem** units, boxtop in **px** units, and box height in **%** units. That is not helping you make the calculations needed to visualize the element sizes. If instead you measured all of the above in **vh** units, you could do something like this:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  height: 100vh;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:5vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container2{
  border:2px solid black;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.boxtop{
  width:auto;
  height:5vh;
  background-color:pink;
}
.gridcontainer{
  display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  height:100%;
}
.box{
  grid-column: span 4 / span 4;
  background-color:yellow;
  height: 85vh;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
   <div class="boxtop"></div>
   <div class="gridcontainer">
     <div class="box">d</div>
     <div class="box">d</div>
   </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, I have kept the total height as **100vh**, padding top and bottom I have applied **5vh** each, and the boxtop height is **5vh**. So the box height, in order to fit the grid, should have to be **(100-5-5-5)vh** or **85vh**. This should also be responsive if you resize the window because all the elements use the same vertical height unit. Hope this helps.